# Bootstrap help-block and Django registration form help_text

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the django.contrib.auth registration form and trying to get the help text to display consistently for all fields using Bootstrap.

I am using the following code in my Django template for the help text as part of a for loop on the form:

```
<p class="help-block">{{ field.help_text }}</p>
```

This works fine apart from the help text for the password field where it displays with the html tags:

[password field help with tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGSU0.png)

To prevent this I changed the code above to:

```
<p class="help-block">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
```

But now the help text is not being formatted by Bootstrap, I guess because of the html inside the paragraph block.

[help-block no longer formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RllE9.png)

Is there an obvious step I'm missing or is there another way this can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, late answer, but you can override the help text in the form, and make it whatever you want.

For example:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password'].help_text = 'Password help text with whatever tags you want.'
```